# su - for some users

Tags: linux, user-accounts, root, privileges, su

in a linux system with

```
su -
```

any user (with root password) can get root privileges.
how I can restrict to some users ?

// similar to `AllowUsers` in `sshd_config`

Comment: The best way to control it is not giving every user the root password. When you give them the root password, you have given up control over what they do. Anything that you do to stop them, they can undo.

Comment: Yup, don't give them root password. If you want them to get restricted administrative privileges, use `sudo` with explicitly allowed binaries. This is still tricky, but at least you have some possibility to actually log what they are using their root privileges for (with maaany caveats if one is not careful). The solution to your specific question is: change the root password and only tell the ones who _should_ have root access the new password.

Comment: [Why GNU su does not support the ‘wheel’ group](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/su-invocation.html#index-wheel-group_002c-not-supported-2361), by RMS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should **not** give the root password to users who do not need full root access.

Keep the root password secret and use `sudo` to give restricted users access to just what they need (see `man sudoers` for some examples)